# Is Titanium 1.8 finally free from the memory starvation issue from release 1.6 and 1.7

Tags: android, ios, html, titanium, appcelerator

Hi there Im new to mobile application development.  I had developed Android apps using Java and is just starting to get the hang of Cocoa Touch and Objective C.  Now I am curious on mobile web application development to create cross platform/device applications which would at least run on Android and iOS(Apple devices: iphone, ipad).  I tried Titanium and developing applications with this framework seems very promising.  Although it is very powerful, popular, mature, documented and very easy to learn I had doubts investing time and to commit on using this framework for my projects after reading this blog which many Titanium users seems to agree with [Why you should stay away from appcelerators titanium](http://usingimho.wordpress.com/2011/06/14/why-you-should-stay-away-from-appcelerators-titanium/).

It seems that release v1.6 sdk and v1.7 sdk have the issue which they describe, the negative comments stopped right after the v1.8 sdk release was out.

My question is, is Titanium v1.8 sdk free from the memory starvation issue and other issues which were discussed on the blog post?

Would you personally recommend this for production use?  And by the way I am using the 1.0.7.201112152014 Titanium build does this use the 1.8 sdk?  Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Take a close look at the progress of comments. It starts from people agreeing with him, and in the end everyone disagrees.

You can select the SDK you wish in the tiapp.xml editor, which is embedded in Titanium Studio. You should indeed use 1.8.x

The platform isn't, and probably never will be, memory issue free. But it also depends on how you build your app.

Stay away as much as you can from includes. And also stay away from creating a window/view/etc. with a file as url in it, this causes most memory issues because it's in a different space.

If you code well, you can use it perfectly without any issues.

Comment: Thanks Topener!  Exactly what I thought I just needed some reassurance of some sort. :)

Comment: I'd recommend this video too (and others from the Codestrong conference) to get an idea of how to develop Titanium apps which are memory efficient: http://player.vimeo.com/video/29804284?title=0&byline=0&portrait=0&color=9a0707&autoplay=1.

Comment: Yeah one issue has been people have been programming their apps similar to how the kitchen sink is architected. Which is a terrible example.  So, take the time to go through their online videos. But we have some production apps on them, some that download 4gb of data and pull up large files and videos and it does alright.  Some modules we had to abandon due to memory leaks, but those have been fixed in 1.7, and imagine 1.8 is even better. We still use it regularly to write mobile apps. No complaints.

Answer (score 1):

Blog post author here. I don't fully agree with Topener - go ahead and read the comments yourself, it's just not true that "in the end everyone disagrees".

For what's worth: my experience is related to version 1.6.2. I've talked to people working with trunk and they told me that the memory issues are far from being resolved.

The only approach that seems to work is, as mentioned in the comments, the Tweetanium approach. But beware, that's not "if you code well". It's "if you code the way Titanium likes". If you take a look at Tweetanium (I suggest you to do it no matter what you decide to do in the end) you'll see that it has a very specific way to deal with architecture. If you follow that path, you should be good. If you think that the way Tweetanium is structured is good for you application, go for it. Be wary though, because (at least in what I consider to be complex) Tweetanium is not very complex, and with growing complexity I found that their approach is difficult to maintain. Again, evaluate for yourself.

Then there's the Android issue. Android support is far from optimal - Wunderlist decided to rewrite their Android version in native, I myself have had huge problems in making anything even remotely complex in iOS working decently on Android. If you need to support only iOS it's alright but, if that's the case, I don't see why you shouldn't write the app directly in Objective-C... considering also the (unavoidable) delay/mismatch between the Titanium and the iOS SDK.

Just my 2c. I suggest you not to take the decision lightly - it costed us a lot.